# Learning data handler in Java?

Tags: java, datahandler

I was aware of it is good to use data handler in Java to transfer files. Anyone can point me a good example or tutorial which help me understand this class.

Also, the package belongs to javax.activation.DataHandler, what is activation mean? is it a special library?

Answer (score 1):

The [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/index.html) for the javax.activation package somewhat clarifies the use of "activation" in the name.

It refers to the [JavaBeans Activation Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-135046.html):

> With the JavaBeans Activation Framework standard extension, developers
>   who use Java technology can take advantage of standard services to
>   determine the type of an arbitrary piece of data, encapsulate access
>   to it, discover the operations available on it, and to instantiate the
>   appropriate bean to perform said operation(s). For example, if a
>   browser obtained a JPEG image, this framework would enable the browser
>   to identify that stream of data as an JPEG image, and from that type,
>   the browser could locate and instantiate an object that could
>   manipulate, or view that image.